# Find all occurrence know string in loaded DOM and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

**Question**

I would like to find out all occurrence of for example "stackoverflow" in loaded DOM using javascript and replace it with "unknown company"
This text can be a value in html text, html attribute, javascript string - generally all places which could be shown to user.

**More details**

1. I cannot search source code, because parts of it are in database, resources, external providers. That is why the easiest way for me is to validate client side.
2. I have a SPA and 99% is downloaded by AJAX
3. I am using backbone mixed with standard ASP.NET MVC (but I think it does not change anything)
4. I cannot provide any code because I do not have an idea how to start

**My ideas**

1. Create global handler on ajax success. Search and replace in `responseText` filtered by content-type:  html, text, json, javascript
2. Read whole DOM into string and make search and replace, but I don't know if it is possible for all above resources.

I hope my question is clear enough, if not I will add more details.

Comment: You're not stealing content from SO and putting it on your own site, are you? Just checking.

Comment: No, I created a site for company X and try to show it safety to company Y :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.myelement').html(function(index, oldHtml) {
    return oldHtml.replace(/stackoverflow/i, 'unknown company');
});
```

Something like that should replace the text on-the-fly for any given element (and children).
It's up to you to see if it's safe to assume that 'stackoverflow' doesn't appear in any HTML attributes, because they might get replaced too.

Comment: This is cool, but works only for html. Do you have an idea how to do same thing in loaded Javascript files?

Comment: You mean the files themselves? Just use an editing program and search/replace. There's no easy way of doing this on-the-fly for files before they're loaded, the most you can try is output buffering and the likes, but that's not what those were meant for. In short, it's overkill. You can do a mass find/replace in an entire directory using file type filters and other stuff in most IDEs and syntax editors (Notepad++ lets you do this out of the box).

Comment: No, I mean response. Instead I will have to run your function continuously. BTW your function does not work on body element.

Comment: Your best solution would be to use it on the relevant areas (you can even use the direct child div of body, it should work there, although I can't see why it didn't work on body directly) the moment they are changed. You can use an interval if you don't wanna call it every other response receive.